# Error Importing TensorFlow: Failed to load the native tensorflow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to install tensorflow with pip and it was successful.

I have seen other answers but I don't understand them.
But when I tried to import tensorflow the following error showed up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: github issue related to yours: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26451#issuecomment-471079686

Answer (score 0):

try to install tensorflow version 1.5:

```
pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow-gpu==1.5
```

But do confirm if the tensor flow you installed matches your system (CPU or GPU)

Comment: I tried the following: pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow==1.15 and the issue continues.